# How can I map all words in the description of a Film to all films' names that contain the word in their description fast?

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

I have a `List<Films> films`, where each film has `int id` and `String description`.
My task is to map each word from all the descriptions to all films names that contain the word in the description, it has to be something like that:

```
<word1>: <filmId11>, <filmId12>,..., <filmId1N>
<word2>: <filmId21>, <filmId22>, ..., <filmId2N>
...
```

I did it using Java Stream API:

```java
private List<Map.Entry<String, String>> wordToFilmIds;

private void addWordsFromDescriptions(List<Film> films) {
        for (Film film : films) {
            String description = film.description();
            String[] tokens = description.split("[\\p{IsPunctuation}\\p{IsWhite_Space}]+");
            allWords.addAll(Arrays.stream(tokens).toList());
        }
        
    }

    private void mapWordsToFilmIDs(List<Films> films) {
        wordToFilmIds = allWords.stream()
                .map(word -> Map.entry(word,
                        films.stream()
                                .filter(film -> film.description().contains(word))
                                .map(film -> String.valueOf(film.id()))
                                .collect(Collectors.joining(","))))
                .toList();

        
    }
```

But the problem is my solution is too slow and I have to work with big numbers, the film's count is about 12 000 and the descriptions are not short. Also, I am `not` permitted to use `multi-threading`.
Any idea how can I optimise it?
Right now the program does not finish.

I also tried using `parallel streams`, still, it was not working.

Comment: Read about [inverted indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) then build a `HashMap<String, Set<Film>>` from all words in film descriptions and your world will change.

Comment: I am new to programming and I have not heard of this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the fact that you are iterating over each film for every word makes the solution O(n^2). It is doable with one iteration though:

Given the helper class:

```java
public class Tuple<A,B> {
    public A a;
    public B b;
    public Tuple(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Try this:

```java
    Map<String, Set<Integer>> addWordsFromDescriptions(List<Film> films) {
        return films.stream()
                .flatMap(film -> tokenizeDescription(film).map(token -> new Tuple<>(token, film)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        tuple -> tuple.a,
                        Collectors.mapping(tuple -> tuple.b.id(), Collectors.toSet())
                ));
    }

    private Stream<String> tokenizeDescription(Film film) {
        return Stream.of(film.description().split("[\\p{IsPunctuation}\\p{IsWhite_Space}]+"));
    }
```

Given the `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`, you can join the ids in the set and get the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static class Film {

    private final String id;
    private final String description;

    public Film(String id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

}

public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Film> films = List.of();
    Map<String, Film> filmById = films.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Film::getId, Function.identity()));
    Map<String, Set<String>> filmByLowerCaseDescriptionWord = createDescriptionMap(films);
}

private static Map<String, Set<String>> createDescriptionMap(List<Film> films) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    films.forEach(film -> Arrays.stream(film.getDescription().split("\\S+"))
                                .map(word -> word.trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))
                                .forEach(lowerCaseWord ->
                                        map.computeIfAbsent(lowerCaseWord, key ->
                                                new HashSet<>()).add(film.getId())));

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, `for-each` loops can be more cleaner and readable than `streams`.

Java-8 introduced [new](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) methods in `Map` interface; `computeIfAbsent` suits well to such situations:

```java
Map<String, Set<Integer>> wordsToFilmIdMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Film film : films) {
   String[] filmDescArray = film.getDesc().split("[\\p{IsPunctuation}\\p{IsWhite_Space}]+");
   for (String descWord : filmDescArray) {
        wordsToFilmIdMap.computeIfAbsent(descWord, unused -> new HashSet<>()).add(film.getId());
   }
}
```